# React-dropzone Ondragend event

Tags: react-dropzone

I was creating the Dropzone component to create Drag-and-Drop Modal in my private webpage. However, I noticed that the React-Dropzone does not contain any `ondragend` event in the documentation, which is given in DnD API of Mozilla.

So, I wanted to ask, if it exists or not and if not, how do I implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using react-dropzone package you can implement it as mentioned below if you need any other help you can refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) in github

```
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone'

onDrop = () => {
  alert('droppped')
}
<Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop}>
  {this.props.childern}
</Dropzone>
```